# Write out tables by grouping in Hive

Tags: hive, apache-pig, grouping, overwrite

Does Hive have the capability to write out a query to different files (e.g. different .csv files) based upon the grouping statement in the query?

For example for a toy data set `extract`:

```
 LName   FName   Car_make   Year
 -----   -----   --------   ----
 Smith   Audrey  Ford       2000
 Smith   Audrey  Ford       2013
 Smith   Audrey  Toyota     1996
 Miller  Heath   Ford       1995
 Miller  Heath   Dodge      1990
 Miller  Heath   Dodge      2010
```

Would like to write out data sets using a group by:

```
INSERT OVERWRITE LOCAL DIRECTORY '/user/drwho/foodf' 
ROW FORMAT DELIMITED 
FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' 
SELECT
  LNAME,
  FNAME,
  CAR_MAKE,
  AVG(YEAR) AS AVERG
FROM EXTRACT
GROUP BY LNAME, FNAME, CAR_MAKE
```

and have output sets SMITH_AUBREY_FORD.csv, SMITH_AUDREY_TOYOTA.csv etc. write out to the local directory. Is this possible in Hive? If no, what about Pig?

EDIT:

I've found while this is not possible in Hive, we can use  @K S Nidhin's suggestion to write the query out to a local directory and instead use awk:

```
 $ cat extract.txt 
 Smith,Audrey,Ford,2000
 Smith,Audrey,Ford,2013
 Smith,Audrey,Toyota,1996
 Miller,Heath,Ford,1995
 Miller,Heath,Dodge,1990
 Miller,Heath,Dodge,2010


 $ awk -F "," '{ print > $1"_"$2"_$3".txt" }' extract.txt
 $ ls -1
 extract.txt
 Miller_Heath_Dodge.txt
 Miller_Heath_Ford.txt
 Smith_Audrey_Ford.txt
 Smith_Audrey_Toyota.txt
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no direct way to output to local directory based on group by. I would suggest the following approach

1. write the Select query with required group by clause into a file name query1.hql
2. hive -f query1.hql > /SMITH_AUBREY_FORD.csv
3. write the other select query into another file query2.hql
4. hive -f query2.hql > /SMITH_AUDREY_TOYOTA.csv

and so on.

Thus you will get the required results stored in your local directory.

Hope this approach helps.